# How to get a rocky texture throughout the mesh?

Tags: sculpting

How to get the rocky texture all throughout the mesh, I obtained this obj from an external source and want to get the get the rocky texture all throughout the mesh

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far that is not working?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this. All I did was use a Noise Texture to slightly warp the vectors of a Voronai Texture to make the "cells" and to give them slightly uneven edges (less straight). Then I just filled in the surface detail by multiplying it again with another Noise Texture. I ran the result through the Height input of a Bump node, and gave it a bit of a gray color and a slight metallic value (to match your image).

[image: Rock]

Comment: Nice work replicating the texture :).

Comment: Any idea how to make a mesh out of it?

Comment: If you mean in detail of your sample image - Bake normal map and use it as texture for Displacement modifier and Apply (but it became very dense  topology). If you are asking for render purpose to get roughness on mesh edges use above node tree attached to Displacement  (you have to enable Experimental Set in Render Properties and  in Material Properties-Settings-Surface-Displacement and Bump. Or better ask a new Q.